# Recursively traversing folders to execute an if statement

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to create a shell script which recursively traverses folders in directories, checks if a file exists, and if it does exist - execute a second script.

I've been able to recursively traverse through the folders and log the current directory, however including an if statement in this command seems to break the process as I think I am misunderstanding syntax.

The following works:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd" \;
```

However doing this gives me a syntax error on line 3, but I can't figure out why?

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && 
if [\(-f "$FILE"\)]; then
sh script.sh" \;
```

If anyone could provide any help as to what is wrong with the syntax on line 3, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't nest double quotes without escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` needs a `fi`, and the quotes must be escaped (using `\"`). While we are at it, the second `\(` `\)` aren't needed.
You can try:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && if [ -f \"$FILE\" ]; then sh script.sh; fi" \;
```

and if it complains about not finding `script.sh`, the full path to `script.sh` can be used (instead of just `script.sh`).

Comment: That's excellent! By the way, the standard procedure in StackOverflow is to accept the answer clicking on the ✓ that the answer has.